# PHP "if ($1 == $2)" comes out as false even though they are the same

Tags: php, if-statement

I have created a website where you can login, atm im working on a page where you can change your password. So i have 3 `<input>` elements, 1 that checks that the "Current password" checks out (this one works fine) and the other 2 is "New Password" and "Confirm password" but when i put them into my if statment it comes out as false.

### HTML form:

`<input name="newpassword" type="password" placeholder="New password"/>`
`<input name="new2password" type="password" placeholder="Confirm password"/>`

### PHP code:

```
if ($newpassword == $new2password) {
    $newhash = password_hash($newpassword, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    $sql = "UPDATE users SET password = $newhash WHERE username = $username";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Password successfully updated";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
} else {
    Echo "Passwords did not match";
}
```

### Simplified:

```
if ($newpassword == $new2password) {
  Echo "Great success";
} else {
  Echo "Passwords did not match";
}
```

Any help to why this dosent work would be awesome.

Comment: Are you sure they're the same? What does` var_dump()` show for each variable? FYI, your PHP is wide open to SQL injections (once you fix your missing quotes that is)..

Comment: Not sure if you pasted all your code but you have an extra curly brace `}` right before the final `else`.

Comment: I didint paste all the code so there is no extra `}` but thanks anyways! Yes i did check it, it's the same. Iv'e check it multiple times. It is wide open to SQL injections? Hmm i gota check that then, thanks man!

Comment: Show the var_dump() of those two variables or else we can't help you

Comment: Why don't you `echo` each password and make sure they are in fact the same?

Comment: from the simplified it looks okay... but can you try few things to debug the issue... 

#1. replace $new2password with variable $cpwd ( just for the sake of debugging )

#2. echo "newpassword length :: ".strlen($newpassword);echo "<br>";echo "confirm password length :: ".strlen($cpwd);

#3. echo "newpassword string :: ".$newpassword;echo "<br>";echo "confirm password string :: ".$cpwd;


#4. echo "checked condition :: ".($newpassword == $cpwd);

Comment: `var_dump($newpassword);
  var_dump($new2password);` gives me: `string(3) "lol" string(3) "lol"` @JohnConde

Comment: @Samuel i did do that, they are the same, check my previous comment and there is a var_dump() :)

Comment: @Ahmad this is all you asked for, does it give you any clues? https://gyazo.com/eba04077c54fbe2801ff6a41bbc5c970

Comment: Rest assured that PHP in this case is not lying to you, but don't believe my words, try yourself: `var_dump($newpassword == $new2password, $newpassword === $new2password);`

Comment: Yep. Works for me: https://3v4l.org/ejaa6

Comment: @hakre that gives me this `bool(false) bool(false) Passwords did not match`

Comment: @JohnConde that basically my code, but mine dosent work

Comment: @Dennis: Do the var_dump before the if. The error is most like how you arrange the code, not the if expression in itself. This is just what debugging looks like :) You need to dig until you find out. I also edited your code in question as there was one bracket too much. That is also a sign that your original code is different to the one in question. So you really need to dig into your code and try there (at the right places to learn more). The two times false show that both variables aren't the same (any longer).

Comment: @Dennis can u re paste the whole html and php because from the picture it seems to be okay... can u try this static condition in the if  , if("lol" == "lol")  , copy paste that and replace the current if condition...

Answer (score 0):

The Else block was in the wrong if statment. Thanks to everyone trying to help.

Comment: Honestly, just delete this question.